# Padding issue on <a> element nested inside <p> element

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a pink call to action button on my home page. My `<a>` element housed inside `<p class="cta">` has the following CSS properties:

```
.cta a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

However the padding on `.cta a` will not expand the `<p>` tag it is contained in. Is there a reason for this and any amendments I can make to my CSS?

The site can be found here:

http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/pg/

Comment: You need `display: block;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor elements are, by browser default, [inline elements](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/).

As per comments, you need to `display:block` your anchor element:

```
.cta a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
}
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/KShgU/1/*